# Xcode 4.2 Сode Signing Error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

OK, I've read every single topic on SO about this problem and I am still have no solution.
Our app was signed for distribution and was in itunesconnect at "Waiting for review", but we found some bugs and rejected it.
After couple of days we were ready to re-submit the app and *"Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed..."* occured.

We done next steps:

1. Creation of new provisioning profile
2. Cleaning the project and Build folder (a lot of times!)
3. Trying another Mac Checking the app with this [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32) and there were no issues found
4. Checking Entitlements and icon file Checking app version and architecture and distribution profile and project.pbxproj file.

Anything missed?

**Added:**

**Command Line input**

codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)' path_i_get_after_drag_and_drop_my_app_to_console

**Results of codesign check:**

myapp.app: valid on disk

myapp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

myapp.app: explicit requirement satisfied

Comment: can you add a -v for verbose to the codesign call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't want to do it (accept own answer) - but in my case the reason of error was in files named like **._picname.png** in folders added to the project as links to folders (blue in Xcode). After these files have been removed the app was succesfully uploaded to Apple Appstore.

Answer (score 5):

Apple have published [TN2250: iOS Code Signing Setup, Process, and Troubleshooting](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html) that should help you, specifically the section [How do I resolve the error: Application failed codesign verification?](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32)

Comment: Thanks, I already been there and posted link to one the articles related in my question. Still no luck.

Comment: **>>and there were no issues found**, as I said above.

Comment: `codesign` gives you a lot more information than that.  Information that may prove useful in **helping you**.

Comment: I've added codesign output to the question, really helpful, isn't it?

Comment: That isn't the output you get from `codesign` when you follow the instructions in TN2250.  It gives you a lot more information than that.  What is the output you get when you follow the instructions in TN2250?  And please don't be so rude to me, all I am doing is trying to help you solve your problem.

Comment: First of all, sorry, didn't want to be rude.
I've put the way I run codesign (and it is very similar to TN2550) and my output is close enough to example from TN2550, so I have no idea what else should be there.
Somehow, I found the reason of the error - in my resource folders added like links (blue ones in Xcode) some file were with names like ._pic.png - cache or something, I guess. After I deleted them all app was succesfully submited to Appstore.
Now should I accept answer above? It's good, RTFM always is good, seriosly, but I want this stuff with resourses names to be shown to developers.

Comment: No, `codesign` should output a lot more than that, such as the signing identity.  I suggest you post the solution you found as a separate answer and accept that.

Comment: OK, and I am going to post full output (when I will get it) from the 'codesign' with old package to find out if it was the way to discover reason of an error.